# Validador de CPF em PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal,

Eu gostaria de saber o que há de errado no meu validador de cpf, feito na linguagem PHP. O que acontece, ele valida o meu CPF, da minha mãe, irmão, namorada e vó. Mas, ao eu testar alguns CPF que peguei de um gerador de cpf online, ele válida alguns e outros não.

Considerem estar recebendo o valor de CPF de formulário via POST de um campo de number (Sem pontuações)

```
<?php 
require_once ("cabecalho.php");
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

if (strlen($cpf) != 11) {
    $_SESSION["danger"] = "O CPF deve conter 11 digítos. Preencha novamente.";
    header("Location: cpf.php");
    die();
}

$verificaJ = $cpf[9];
$verificaK = $cpf[10];

$J_letra = 10;
$J_array = array();
for ($i < 0; $i <= 8; $i++){
    $J_array[] = $cpf[$i] * $J_letra;
    $J_letra--;
    $J_soma = $J_soma + $J_array[$i];
}

$J_resto = $J_soma % 11;
$J_subtracao = 11 - $J_resto;

if ($J_subtracao > 9) {
    $J = 0;
    echo "J:" . $J . "<br> ";
} else {
    $J = $J_subtracao;
    echo "J else:" . $J . "<br>";
}

//Conseguindo K
$K_letra = 11;
$K_array = array();
for ($ii < 0; $ii <= 9; $ii++){
    $K_array[] = $cpf[$ii] * $K_letra;
    $K_letra--;
    $K_soma = $K_soma + $K_array[$ii];
}

$K_resto = $K_soma % 11;
$K_subtracao = 11 - $K_resto;
if ($K_subtracao > 9) {
    $K = 0;
    echo "K:" . $K . "<br> ";

} else {
    $K = $K_subtracao;
    echo "K:" . $K . "<br> ";

}

if ($verificaJ == $J && $verificaK == $K){
   echo "CPF VÁLIDO";
} else {
  echo "CPF INVÁLIDO";
}
```

Ps: Eu sei que o código não está muito elegante. Mas por favor, eu quero saber o erro deste código, e não pegar um da internet pronto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está no valor do `$i` no laço `for`. O valor atribuído deveria ser `$i = 0` e não `$i < 0`. Com isso o `$i` só passa a ter valor, e de `1`, após a primeira volta do laço, ignorando o índice `0` da array, resultando na soma errada dos cálculos.

Basta corrigir o valor do `$i` nos dois laços `for` do código, trocando `$i < 0` e `$ii < 0` por `$i = 0` e `$ii = 0` respectivamente.

Veja o mesmo código rodando em JavaScript (os CPFs válidos foram gerados em um site gerador de CPF):

```js
function validaCPF($cpf){

   $verificaJ = $cpf[9];
   $verificaK = $cpf[10];
   
   $J_letra = 10;
   $J_array = [];
   $J_soma = 0;
   for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++){
       $J_array.push($cpf[$i] * $J_letra);
       $J_letra--;
       $J_soma = $J_soma + $J_array[$i];
   }
   
   $J_resto = $J_soma % 11;
   $J_subtracao = 11 - $J_resto;
   
   if ($J_subtracao > 9) {
       $J = 0;
   } else {
       $J = $J_subtracao;
   }
   
   //Conseguindo K
   $K_letra = 11;
   $K_array = [];
   $K_soma = 0;
   for ($ii = 0; $ii <= 9; $ii++){
       $K_array.push($cpf[$ii] * $K_letra);
       $K_letra--;
       $K_soma = $K_soma + $K_array[$ii];
   }
   
   $K_resto = $K_soma % 11;
   $K_subtracao = 11 - $K_resto;
   if ($K_subtracao > 9) {
       $K = 0;
   
   } else {
       $K = $K_subtracao;
   
   }
   
   if ($verificaJ == $J && $verificaK == $K){
      return $cpf+": CPF VÁLIDO";
   } else {
     return $cpf+": CPF INVÁLIDO";
   }
}

console.log(validaCPF('59848265007')); // válido
console.log(validaCPF('59848265008')); // inválido
console.log(validaCPF('55688772034')); // válido
console.log(validaCPF('55688772033')); // inválido
```

```html
<p>Digite um CPF</p>
<input type="text" id="cpf" style="width: 200px; font-size: 30px;">
<button onclick="console.clear(); console.log(validaCPF(document.getElementById('cpf').value))">OK</button>
```

Comment: Nossa, fazia tanto tempo que eu só utilizava foreach que nem percebi que o erro estava no meu for escrito errado. Muito obrigado ! Realmente era isso. :D

Comment: Para funcionar no php galera, é só substituir os dois push por array_push e colocar os valores de atribuição de cada um que fica assim respectivamente:
array_push($J_array, $cpf[$i] * $J_letra);
array_push($K_array, $cpf[$ii] * $K_letra);